# Unable to Insert FormulaArray in Cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

I'm trying to insert an array formula into a specific cell, but always receive the error "Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the range class".

This is my code in VBA:

```
Cells(2, Price).FormulaArray = Replace(Range("lookuppriceMP"), "'", "")
```

And this is the formula in the named range "lookuppriceMP", which should then look for a specific value in a table on a different worksheet:

```
'=INDEX(store_xx17[[Date]:[PriceAmount]];VERGLEICH(1;(store_xx17[Date]=[@Date])*(store_xx17[InArea]=[@InArea])*(store_xx17[OutArea]=[@OutArea]);0);9)
```

*My system is set to German because of the "VERGLEICH", which is the same as "MATCH"*

1) Inserting the formula directly in the cell and pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter does work perfectly
2) The current formula string is only 144 characters long (limit for FormulaArray is 225)
2) Replacing the formula in the named range by e.g. "'=1+1" works
3) Inserting other formulas the same way with the German expressions works as well

I'm honestly out of ideas, why it won't let me insert this specific formula... Any suggestions?

Comment: the problem is that the ending formula must be in american english format, when going through vba, or one must use the `local` type of formula.  But there is no `.FormulaArrayLocal`

Comment: So you will need to replace `VERGLEICH` with `MATCH` and all the `;` with `,` also.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks a lot Scott. Already thought that it is just a small thing I'm missing...